# Problemas em pegar arquivos com acentuação no Tomcat 8!

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Tenho a mesma aplicação no *tomcat 7* e no *tomcat 8*, somente no *tomcat 8* da um problema, eu seto o *src* de uma imagem mas nos arquivos das imagens que tem acentuação da um erro de "not found", segue imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

nome do arquivo: `FAVORITOS-MENU - SEM SELEÇÃO_e86aff0a5ad040e3b0232a075079dd46.png`

se eu mudo `SELE%C7%C3O` por `SELEÇÃO` direto no link funciona normalmente...
e lembrando no *Tomcat 7* funciona normalmente!

Comment: I Solve this, I had to put "URIEncoding="ISO-8859-1"" on conf/server.xml, contrary to what I found in tutorials that spoke to put "UTF-8".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, eu tive que colocar `URIEncoding="ISO-8859-1` no conf/server.xml, ao contrario que encontrei na internet que falava para colocar "UTF-8":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]